# Spring Dependency Injection for Inherited methods

Tags: java, spring

Below mentioned is a snippet of a code:-

```
class A
{
  protected B()
  {
    int x=5; //line 1
  }
}

class C extends A
{
  protected B()
  {
    int x=6; //line 2
  }
}
```

How can I use spring dependency injection in such a way that only **line 2** will be used in the program and **not line 1** ?